# What is the use case of putting everything under another level named "data" a JSON API

Tags: json, api, data-structures, representation

Many times I see JSON API's having the form

```
{
  data: {
    ...
  }
}
```

There is a whole level under `data` and everything is under it, rarely is there something beside. Do you know why do they design API like that? What is the main use case? Why complicate it? What do you put beside it? Metadata? Keywords? Associaitions? Versions?

Answer (score 0):

I usually reserve the root for status, and "data" for an actual serialized object

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a "JSON API" standard. https://jsonapi.org/

They use `data` there.

Answer (score 0):

Structures like this are common with API's that wrap all responses in some metadata-esque object. For example, given a C# class:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    string ApplicationMessage { get; set; }
    Exception Exception { get; set; }
    object Data { get; set; }
}
```

By always returning classes that derive from `Response<T>`, the client code can inspect the metadata properties to gain further insight into the response, if necessary.

For example, let's say:

### Request

GET api.com/users/HunorKovács

### Response

**400 Bad Request**

Body:

```
{
    "applicationMessage": "Expected a userId, not a username.",
    "exception": null,
    "data": null
}
```

The `ApplicationMessage` in this case gives details about why the 400 response was returned. Exceptions could be passed along for easier debugging in dev environments, etc.

For normal requests that have no issues, you'd likely only see the data being populated:

### Request

GET api.com/users/1474495

### Response

200 OK

Body:

```
{
    "applicationMessage": null,
    "exception": null,
    "data": {
        "userId": 1474495,
        "fullName": "HunorKovács"
    }
}
```